# Trying to set up new details for a current user

Tags: java

I'm very new to programming and my knowledge of java is limited. I'm tinkering with a template for a facebook like website so i can learn and add features. I'm trying to allow the current user to change their details, such as name, email, password etc., but cant figure out the java to do so. When i try, all that happens is a brand new user is created on top of the current one :/ 
Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void changeDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String age, String nationality)
  {
    Logger.info("New details are: " + firstName + " " + lastName + " " + email + " " + password + " " + age + " " + nationality + " ");

    User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email, password, age, nationality);
    user.save();
    Home.index();
  }
```

and here is the user class:

```
package models;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import controllers.Home;
import play.db.jpa.Model;
import play.db.jpa.Blob;

@Entity
public class User extends Model
{
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
  public String email;
  public String password;
  public String age;
  public String nationality;
  public String statusText;
  public Blob   profilePicture;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sourceUser")
  public List<Friendship> friendships = new ArrayList<Friendship>();

  public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String age, String nationality)
  {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.age = age;
    this.nationality = nationality;
  }


  public static User findByEmail(String email)
  {
    return find("email", email).first();
  }

  public boolean checkPassword(String password)
  {
    return this.password.equals(password);
  }

  public void befriend(User friend)
  {
    Friendship friendship = new Friendship(this, friend);
    friendships.add(friendship);
    friendship.save();
    save();
  }

  public void unfriend(User friend)
  {
    Friendship thisFriendship = null;

    for (Friendship friendship:friendships)
    {
      if (friendship.targetUser== friend)
      {
        thisFriendship = friendship;
      }
    }
    friendships.remove(thisFriendship);
    thisFriendship.delete();
    save();
  }

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "to")
  public List<Message> inbox = new ArrayList<Message>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "from")
  public List<Message> outbox = new ArrayList<Message>();

  public void sendMessage (User to, String messageText)
  {
    Message message = new Message (this, to, messageText);
    outbox.add(message);
    to.inbox.add(message);
    message.save();
  } 



}
```

I can see my problem is probably "new User  and user.save" but I cant  figure out what I should have in. thanks for your help :)

Comment: What libraries do you use? How is `User` implemented? What does `Home.index()` do?

Comment: If you want to allow current user to change their details, you should have something(i.e. primary key) that recognizes current user and then update that user.

Comment: Without the meat (code behind User class and possibly Home) we can't help you much...

Comment: You are creating a new user on every method call to `changeDetails`. You should either pass the user reference within the `changeDetails` method so that you can mutate the attributes (firstname,lname etc) with the new values. Alternatively You should consider encapsulating this method inside the User class. The latter is more Object oriented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass instance of the User class to the changeDetails method and change it`s attributes with setter methods.

**EDIT :**

Added comments to your code to see what is wrong :

```
public static void changeDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String age, String nationality)
  {
    Logger.info("New details are: " + firstName + " " + lastName + " " + email + " " + password + " " + age + " " + nationality + " ");

    //here you are creating new user object and setting it`s properties, wrong
    User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email, password, age, nationality); 
    user.save();
    Home.index();
  }
```

Suggested fixes (assuming you have setter methods in User class) :

```
public static void changeDetails(User user, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String age, String nationality)
  {
    Logger.info("New details are: " + firstName + " " + lastName + " " + email + " " + password + " " + age + " " + nationality + " ");

    user.setfirstName(firstName);
    user.setlastName(lastName);
    user.setEmail(email); 
    user.setPassword(password); 
    user.setAge(age); 
    user.setNationality(nationality);

    Home.index();
  }
```

Or after seeing your edit and more code that you do not have setter methods, do this :

```
public static void changeDetails(User user, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String age, String nationality)
  {
    Logger.info("New details are: " + firstName + " " + lastName + " " + email + " " + password + " " + age + " " + nationality + " ");

    user.firstName = firstName;
    user.lastName = lastName;
    user.email = email; 
    user.password = password; 
    user.age = age; 
    user.nationality = nationality;

    Home.index();
  }
```

Comment: is that not what i am doing? I have named each property at the start?

Comment: Ok I've done what you said but if I leave out user.save() nothing happens but if I put it in it just creates a new user still. appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Althogh its not clear implementation of your user.save() method.
One thing is clear your guess is right. It's because of new User() which creates a new user for you.

Check your user class is there any property to uniquely identify a user(such as id).
And while you are changing details pass that unique id property along with other details which will say details for which user needs to be updated.

Again if you are using any persistence api like hibernate then setting unique id properties is enough to update details, other wise you have to write your custom code first get detail of the user with unique id and then update the details

Again your in your code there is no primary key declaration for any properties and i can't find save method in User class. I am assuming you are using hibernate.

According to the code for User class i am assuming email properties is the unique id you are using so change your changeDetails method like this

```
public static void changeDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String age, String nationality)
  {
    Logger.info("New details are: " + firstName + " " + lastName + " " + email + " " + password + " " + age + " " + nationality + " ");
    User user = findByEmail(String email);
    //User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email, password, age, nationality);
    user.setFirstName(firstName);
    user.setLastName(lastName);
    //user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.setAge(age);
    user.setNationality(nationality);
    user.save();
    Home.index();
  }
```

As you can see i have commented user.setEmail(email) because it will say its a new user and will save it as a new user.

Comment: Yes, the template I have does have instances where it uses id. However I can't get id to work. This is what I have tried to no avail: User user = User.findById(Long.parseLong(userId)

Comment: can you post the whole code for your user class so we can actually se what you are doing in user.save method as well as where you are calling User.findById(userId) and how you are using this user object.

Comment: I've made the changes but am still getting a brand new user because of the user.save() method, if i leave it out nothing happens. thanks so much for your help so far, at least im learning!

Comment: @Krang it's important to see implementation of your User.save() method
to help further. can you share it. and please do tell weather you are using simple JDBC or using hibernate or anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using simple JDBC. As far as I can tell, I am just using import play.db.jpa.Model; to make that method work. I didn't write that part of it myself so not sure what else i could do really?

Comment: in your class User you have not set id for any of the field
see the documentation here http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.2/jpa

You make a field as id with @Id annotation then search user by inbuilt method findById(id)

or create a method findUserByEmail with your query and then set the new values of field through setter method and then call User.save() method.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks @Ravi Kumar, that worked for me! I can't give you reputation on this yet because it won't allow me but as soon as I can I will. Thanks again for all your help :)